# Never before had a problem with Ubuntu desktop graphical display; Trying to use nvidia GT630

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gui

I've been using ubuntu since 9.04 and never had a problem with Ubuntu bringing up the desktop graphical user interface.  However I am currently not able to see anything graphical past the install screens.

I have an Intel DP55KG motherboard and just installed an nvidia gt630 graphics card (zotac), since the old graphics card failed.

I can install the server and see text.  So I do a apt-get install ubuntu-desktop...or apt-get install kubuntu-desktop...or apt-get install xubuntu desktop, but after the reboot there is no display...its like something is hung up.  I tried using the Live quantal dvd and I do see the graphical prompt to try without installing, but after that the screen goes blank.  I've tried two monitors and the same thing happens.  There is a faint "glow" on the screen and I do not get a "no input signal" from the monitor, so something is happening.

I can install an old OEM of XP so I know the video card and motherboard are at least semi functional.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: did you just upgrade to 12.10/quantal quetzal?

Comment: No, what happened is I moved.  When setting up at the new house I got no display at all, so I bought a new video card...at first a Radeon something...same thing happened, so I returned it and got the nvidia gt630 thinking that would fix the problem, but no.  I had an install of 11.04, but that hung on boot so I wanted to see if I could at least get to a desktop with a live DVD.

Comment: The hang on boot is, I believe, a separate issue that I need to deal with too.  Boot seems to hang on probe of e1000 intel built-in nic.  Never did that before.

Comment: On the card, I've tried the mini-hdmi out, both dvi outs and a dvi out converted to vga and all the same result...I can see the ubuntu splash screen, but after that just a glow and nothing on the screen.

Comment: I can get to a GUI desktop with a Live FreeBSD image, but my bluetooth mouse is not recognized, so I can't test it out. Downloading Solaris11, Debian now to test them out.  Mint showed the splash screen, then my system rebooted.  Tried Mint in compatibility mode and it hung.

Comment: I disabled the internal nic in bios and still got a hang, this time at rt2800pci ...so I removed my wireless PCI card and I am now able to boot to GUI desktop.  So seems like the problem is some OSs allow bypass of hangs and some don't.  All good now...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

This was an issue with the boot process hanging not with anything video related!

At first my video card failed, which I replaced. When I could not boot to desktop, I used recovery mode to see the boot process hang at intel e1000. So I disabled internal lan in bios.

Still the thing wouldn't boot to desktop. I used the recovery mode again and found the boot process hanging on rt2800pci ! So I removed my airlink wireless card and...presto!...I can boot to GUI desktop.

Strange to me that some OSs (Live FreeBSD) don't get hung up on hangs while others do. Also strange to me that Ubuntu server doesn't get hung up, but when overlaying ubuntu-desktop or kubuntu-desktop or xubuntu desktop it does!

Lesson: Always start trouble-shooting the recovery mode issue!

This event was two network hardware failures. I got distracted thinking it was a video issue because of the different behavior of server boot and server with gui overlay boot.